# Finding out which website a user is coming from using Javascript

Tags: javascript

So using javascript, I'd like to know if there's a way to find out where a user is coming from, save it to a variable and use that address later.

For example: I give an ad banner to various websites, and when a user clicks on the banner, they come to my online store, and if they buy anything, I want to know which website they came from, and how much they spent shopping on my website.

Is there a way to do that with javascript?

Is there a way to use a cookie to store the inbound url, and then after someone buys something, just email that someone coming from "websiteHere.com" bought something on your website? and then the cookie gets deleted, or is that bad practice?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp `document.referrer`

Comment: i think it's impossible to get to know how much they bought items on other website

Comment: I mean to say how much they bought from my website.

Comment: @DLeh Thanks for that information. That's half of what I need down. Making progress.

Comment: know where they come from isn't a pb (document referrer as say DLeh).
But to know how much they spent on your. it's not the same. You try to recreate google analityc? :).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd generate a unique URL for each ad banner.

```
mysite.com/?bannerid=123456
```

Then your e-commerce software would associate that banner ID with the user session and record this as part of the transaction. You should be doing this on the server anyway, not with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Captain, assuming you are trying to market your store using online banner, for now what i can think of is when you provide them your banner, you will have to give them some information to link that banner to your online store, all you have to do is to tell them to add their website information like ( source='www.myfriendwebsite.com' **OR a banner id** ) into the link that they are clicking on. Following is just an example..

```
<a href="www.myawsomeonlinestore.com?source='www.myfriendwebsite.com'"><img src="onlinestorebanner.gif"></a>
```

Now the key is you have to track their clicks, if you can successfully track their clicks like the way i mentioned above, you know exactly what your user is doing, then you build a logic in your program to calculate how much they bought or whatever ...

If i can think of a better solution, i will update my post